# Ubuntu 18.04.3 crashes on VirtualBox VM in Windows 10 Pro (1903)

Tags: 18.04, dell, 64-bit, windows-10

My system is:

- Dell Latitude 7400 i5-8265U with Windows 10 Pro (1903)
- VirtualBox 6.0.12
- Ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64
- 1024MB RAM is assigned to VM (by default).

After clicking on "Try Ubuntu or Install", Ubuntu 18.04.3 crashes, the screen freezes/goes to full black, and nothing else.

What's the solution?

Comment: As far as I remember, minimum requirement for 18.04 is 2GB RAM unless that's a minimal installation.

Comment: @Kulfy Thanks for reply. VirtualBox was suggesting 1024MB, hence I went with that. After adding 1024MB RAM, so total memory 2048MB. It fixed this problem, I was able to install Ubuntu 18.04.3, no problems so far now. Thanks very much.